# EndeavourOS freezes when unplugged

Tags: linux-kernel, dual-boot, endeavouros

I have a dual-boot of Windows 11 and EndeavourOS, The problem occurs when I unplug the charger it freezes after some time not immediately, but this does not happen when the pc is plugged in. I have also tried downgrading the Linux kernel but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: `I have also tried downgrading the Linux kernel` - what made you think the kernel version is the issue? Did you find something somewhere in your research into the issue that suggested the kernel version was a potential issue?

Comment: Yes, I saw a video on it by Chris Titus Tech

Comment: how old was the video?

Comment: 2 years old, why?, https://youtu.be/HCBLuVtdOIk

Comment: so, whats the "default" kernel, and what's the one you tried? - also, I gather this is some sort of laptop - details of the laptop may help fix the issue

Comment: The kernel I am using now is 5.15.6-arch2-1 and the kernel I tried was 5.15.4. Cpu - Intel i5-8265U (8) @ 3.900GHz, GPU - Intel WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Gr, 8gb ddr4 ram, its a Hp notebook

Comment: are either of those kernels "LTS" -that's what Chris suggests, using the most recent LTS kernel as it's considered stable

Comment: I switched to Linux-lts kernel and the problem didn't occur while in lts but I couldn't get the wifi to work so I switched to the zen kernel and so far it works great and it doesn't freeze.